# Почему выдаёт ошибку java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0?

Tags: java

У меня есть две картинки, они кликабельные, нажимая на эти картинки, я меняю цвет Action Bar. Но один код работает отлично, другой абсолютно такой же , но немного с другими названиями не работает.

**1 КОД**

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ShaPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ShaPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String hexColor = sharedPreferences.getString("toolbarColor", "");
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(hexColor)));

pinkcolor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String hexColor = "#eca190";
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(hexColor)));
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("toolbarColor",hexColor);
            editor.commit();

        }
});
```

**2 КОД**

```
sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("ShaPreferences1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("ShaPreferences1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String hexColor1 = sharedPreferences1.getString("toolbar", "");
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(hexColor1)));



greencolor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String hexColor1 = "#8bc34a";
                getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(hexColor1)));
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor1=sharedPreferences1.edit();
                editor1.putString("toolbar",hexColor1);
                editor1.commit();
            }
        });
```

Ошибку выдает на:

```
 getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(hexColor1)));
```

Сама ошибка:

> Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0;
>   index=0

Comment: Эта строка в примере кода встречается дважды, ошибка возникает при инициализаци или при щелчке? Приведите полную трассировку стека по исключению, чтобы было однозначно ясно в каком классе оно возникает.

Comment: когда я нажимаю на activity, где расположены две эти картинки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам надо отработать ситуацию когда цвет еще не сохранен в настройках.

Вместо:

```
String hexColor = sharedPreferences.getString("toolbarColor", "");
String hexColor1 = sharedPreferences1.getString("toolbar", "");
```

Сделайте так:

```
String hexColor = sharedPreferences.getString("toolbarColor", "#eca190");
String hexColor1 = sharedPreferences1.getString("toolbar", "#8bc34a");
```

Это означает, что если **toolbarColor** или **toolbar** будут пустыми, то в переменные попадет значение которое вы задали по умолчанию

```
sharedPreferences.getString("toolbarColor", "ваше значение по умолчанию если toolbarColor пустой")
sharedPreferences1.getString("toolbar", "ваше значение по умолчанию если toolbar пустой")
```

Пояснение почему "первый код" работает а второй - нет: в первом случае вы сначала реализовали сохранение параметра, а потом добавили установку цвета. Во втором случае вы скопировали "первый код" но новая переменная toolbar пустая, потому что вы еще не сохранили её в настройки, но уже пытаетесь её загрузить, перевести в цвет и установить цвет.

Дополнительно. Вам нужно менять цвет тулбара из разных картинок. Значит у вас должна быть одна переменная, пусть будет **toolbarColor**, и единое имя общих настроек **ShaPreferences**

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ShaPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String hexColor = sharedPreferences.getString("toolbarColor", "#eca190"); // <-- по умолчанию розовый цвет
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(hexColor)));

pinkcolor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String hexColor = "#eca190";
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(hexColor)));
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("toolbarColor",hexColor);
            editor.commit();

        }
});

greencolor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String hexColor1 = "#8bc34a";
                getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(hexColor1)));
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor1=sharedPreferences1.edit();
                editor1.putString("toolbarColor",hexColor1);
                editor1.commit();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Ошибка прошла, но теперь Action Bar не сохраняет цвет, когда я нажимаю на картинку, а если одну картинку убрать, то без нажатия на картинку, он уже присваивает Action Bar цвет, как быть?

Comment: Так вы сохраняете цвет в разные переменные, а вам надо в одну переменную сохранять.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало!

Answer (score -1):

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: offset=0 length=46 string.length()=24
at net.kdt.pojavlaunch.Logger.appendToLog(Native Method)
at net.kdt.pojavlaunch.JavaGUILauncherActivity.lambda$onCreate$4$net-kdt-pojavlaunch-JavaGUILauncherActivity(JavaGUILauncherActivity.java:177)
at net.kdt.pojavlaunch.JavaGUILauncherActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:8)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]